# iPhone css hover should go back normal 'unhover'

Tags: iphone, css, hover, back, mode

I'm working on a web app for the iPhone…

I made a 'button' with the following CSS, when you tap it (:hover) it changes, but when you release, it should go back to normal mode… How do i do that ?

```
.button {
height:40px;
width:95px;
margin-top:10px;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:14px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #558544 0%, #5EA83D 100%);
border-radius: 12px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#558544;
border-width:5px; }

.button:hover {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #5EA83D 0%, #558544 100%);
}
```

Comment: if this is just for iOS, don't use `:hover` since it's somewhat arbitrary (or so it seems) how it actually get implemented on the touch device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover in CSS doesn't work like that. Instead you will have to use touch specific javascript (`ontouchstart` and `ontouchend`) and add some class to the button that represents the "down" state.

For example HTML like this

```
<div class="button" ontouchstart="buttonTouchStart(event)" ontouchend="buttonTouchEnd(event)" ></div>
```

and javascript like this

```
var buttonTouchStart = function(e) {
    var t = e.target;
    t.className = "button down";
}

var buttonTouchEnd = function(e) {
    var t = e.target;
    t.className = "button";
}
```

You should probably also use media queries to disable the hover CSS for the devices that are targeted by the Javascript.